# lods behavior when there's no data segment

Tags: assembly

Educational question, so if there are any materials, please post them.

Normally, the lods assembly instruction loads a byte / word / double word from DS:EDI into AL / AX / EAX.
So, in order to do that, there needs to be a segment to which DS will point.

But what happens if I make only a .code segment, I don't bother putting anything into DS, and I use the lods (or lodsb / lodsw / lodsd) ?

I know that I can make it use other register, for example

```
lods DWORD PTR SS:[ESI]
```

But let's say I just have no data. Will it try to take something from a protected memory region causing a crash / error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segment register addresses aren't the same as program segments. In a 32-bit assembly, segment register contains a segment selector, which selects a segment previously defined in general/local descriptor table. I won't go into details here, but manipulation with segment registers and descriptor tables is handled by operating system, and segmentation isn't that important as it used to be before 80386.

The segments or sections you mention in assembly sources are nowadays used to sort data with similar purpose into larger blocks (usually sections). As these sections have similar purpose (they're being used in similar way/only in some ways), they can be placed into memory with some access restrictions, so that code would be executable but not writable, and data would be writable but not executable.

Meaning of terms `section` and `segment` is different among executable file formats and it's always necessary to check it in format specification.

`CS`, `DS` and `ES` (+maybe `SS`) mostly refer to the same segment descriptor containing most of virtual memory. You don't need to care about what is in them, actually, you also shouldn't. Your linker will calculate addresses of sections in your code, align them and then replace every usage of some symbol to be pointing exactly where your data is.

**TL;DR**: Content of your segment register doesn't have any meaning for you and it has no connection with segments you define in assembly source. `LODxx` instruction can use any segment register (`segment override prefix` is making it possible) but `ESI` register must be used as the source index.

Comment: So, if all segment registers point to the same memory area, something like xor edi, edi lods will go to the start of the current memory area?

Comment: Yes, but dereferencing a null offset will give you an exception. There's a guard page at low addresses; read up about paging in the CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Most 32-bit operating systems use "flat" memory layout so the segment registers CS, DS, ES, FS, GS and SS point to the same memory area.

If your executable has a .data segment or not does not matter at all.

However there are two questions that could be interesting:

- What happens if ESI contains an invalid value (not pointing to any segment)?
- What happens if the DS register contains some useless value? (in 32-bit OSs you typically do not modify this register)

In both cases an exception would occur which means that the operating system is notified. In Windows you would see this "general protection fault" message box...

In "real mode" (8086 mode) any value of DS and SI (not ESI) would form a valid address so the "lods" instruction never fails in 8086 mode.